# What is the meaning of "Life is true to form..."?

Tags: meaning, definition

I've come to read this Mark Spitz' quote:

> Life is true to form; records are meant to be broken.

Second part is 100% clear to me and surprisingly the first part is nearly none percent. I'm not good enough in English to understand it. I understand all words of "Life is true to form" seperately and seen them very frequently elsewhere but all together, I can't make a meaning.

Can you help?

Comment: "True to form" means behaving or proceeding in the usual way, in the expected manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"life is true to form"
To simplify it
"Life works exactly as expected" 
Don't feel bad about not understanding it, I'm a native speaker and I had to think about it for a minute.